# How do you add a source set to a Java project in gradle 2.1?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-2

How do you add a source set to a Java project in gradle 2.1?

I've read the docs on the [Java Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) and [SourceSetOutput](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html) and a few other SO threads and I'm still struggling to figure out how it works.

I created a simple build script to test my understanding. Based on Section 23.7.2, example 23.5 of the User Guide, it appears I can create a sourceSet by doing:

```
sourceSets {
   generated
}
```

In section 23.4. Project layout seems to imply that this all I need to do because my source set follows the gradle convention. Code to be included in the source set is in `src/generated/java/packagename`. and will be automatically added to the classpath. Based on the symbol not found errors I'm getting from code that uses code defined in the generated source set, I assume that this incorrect and something else needs to be done. What do I need to do?

Here's my setup:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "tester.Test"

sourceSets {
    generated
}
```

**File structure**

```
tester/
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── main
│   ├── dependency-cache
│   └── tmp
│       └── compileJava
├── build.gradle
└── src
    ├── generated
    │   └── java
    │       └── tester
    │           └── Boom.java
    └── main
        └── java
            └── tester
                └── Test.java
```

**Boom.java**

```
package tester;

class Boom {
   String sound;

   public Boom (String s){
      sound = s;
   }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
package tester;

class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Boom b = new Boom("KABOOM");

      System.out.println("I've run");
      System.out.println(b.sound);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `build.gradle` in the following way:

```
sourceSets {
    generated
    main {
        compileClasspath += generated.output  // adds the sourceSet to the compileClassPath
        runtimeClasspath += generated.output  // adds the sourceSet to the runtimeClasspath
    }
}

project.run.classpath += sourceSets.generated.output //add the sourceSet to project class path
```

Remember that adding new source set is something different from having compiled source set in the classpath.

The line below the source sets is necessary for `run` task to work.

Comment: Thanks! This works for `gradle build`, however, when I try `gradle run` it gives me a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Hmm.. Indeed. I've also tested it with `run` but unfortunately without `clean`. Will have a look.

Comment: What I learned: Conceptually, sourceSets are boxes around collections of code. Even though you are using the java plugin, you'll still need to tell gradle how to use the information. Using a source set allows you to compile/test collections of your code separately. 

To use it in your project, you need to tell gradle how to use it. See the answer above for one example.

Thanks @Opal!

Comment: Yes, but mind the fact that not all runtime classpaths are modifiable - some of them can't be changed. Also gradle comes with some reasonable default, if You do something beyond the default usage You need to *tell* gradle about it.

Comment: Good points. Do you know where I can find out the details of what `Project` includes on the classPath? Since we're talking about, if I added tests, would I need to add the "generated" source set to the the test source set's path too?

Comment: It's not the `project` that owns the classpath. In this case `run` task has the classpath. See here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/ccddc438ce09293d84030ebe31668d739c8a228a/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/ApplicationPlugin.groovy. I guess `generated` source also may be added to tests.